# React does not recognize the `backgroundColor` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, styled-components

I've been searching about this error a while but couldn't find a solution...
I'm using styled components and ant.design.

Button Component

```
import React from 'react'
import {Btn} from './style';

const ComponentButton = (props) =>{

  const  {title, backgroundColor,color, hoverColor, handleClick,shape} = props

 return(
      <Btn 
        shape={shape || "round"} 
        onClick={handleClick}
        backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
        color={color}
        hoverColor={hoverColor}
      >
         {title}   
      </Btn>
  )
}

export default ComponentButton;
```

styled-Component

```
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';
import {primaryColor, white} from '../../../../config';
import { Button } from 'antd';



export const Btn = styled(Button)`
   ${(props, {color, backgroundColor, hoverColor, width} = props) =>
      css`
        color: ${color ? color : white};
        background-color: ${backgroundColor ? backgroundColor : primaryColor} !important; 
        width: ${`${width}px` ? `${width}px` : '-webkit-fill-available'};
        border: none !important;

        &:hover, &:focus{
          color: ${hoverColor ? hoverColor : white};
          border: none !important;
        }
        &:after{
          box-shadow: none !important;
        }

    `} 
`
```

I don't know why I still getting this error:

React does not recognize the `backgroundColor` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `backgroundcolor` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`styled-components` will automatically add all props into DOM element by default, such as:

```
  <button backgroundColor="" color="" hoverColor="" ... />
```

and [react will check the props of the DOM element are legal](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html).

also, this line `${(props, {color, backgroundColor, hoverColor, width} = props)` looks a little weird, this should only have one parameter.

you can try this:

```
// avoid pass all props into button element
export const Btn = styled(({color, backgroundColor, hoverColor, width, ...props}) => <Button {...props} />)`
   ${(p = props) =>
      css`
        color: ${p.color ? p.color : white};
        background-color: ${p.backgroundColor ? p.backgroundColor : primaryColor} !important; 
        width: ${`${p.width}px` ? `${p.width}px` : '-webkit-fill-available'};
        border: none !important;

        &:hover, &:focus{
          color: ${p.hoverColor ? p.hoverColor : white};
          border: none !important;
        }
        &:after{
          box-shadow: none !important;
        }

    `} 
`
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you arrive here because of the error message in the title: Here's a solution for the problem in the world of `react` and `javascript`:

```
/**
 * This layer of *styled* will make the error go away
 **/
const StylableButton = styled.button({}, (props) => ({
  ...props,
  
  // Just in case you'd use typescript:
  //...(props as any),
}));


/**
 * Your custom button component
 **/
const MyButton= (props) => {
    return <StylableButton {...props} />;
};
```

Using it like this:

```
  const MyStyledButton = styled(MyButton)({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  })
```

### Code for your case

Answer (score 0):

change backgroundColor to backgroundcolor (without camelCase)